# More than 1 rows returned from SELECT inside SELECT

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions, workbench

I'm trying to create a query to find what is the total amount owed by each customer to the company. It is the `GROUP BY customerNumber` in the sub query that is creating the problem.

```
SELECT customerName,
       customers.customerNumber,
       SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) - ( SELECT SUM(amount) AS MoneyPayed FROM payments GROUP BY customerNumber ) AS AmountOwed
FROM payments
INNER JOIN customers ON payments.customerNumber = customers.customerNumber
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
INNER JOIN  orderdetails ON  orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber
GROUP BY customerNumber;
```

The tables I'm trying to link are `payments` and `orderdetails`.

When I get rid of the `GROUP BY` I get results in negatives as the total `SUM` of amount is subtracted from each row of `SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach)`.

How can I change this so that I can return multiple rows from payments to subtract from `SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach)` from the order details table.

Link to DB as StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post images

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6o1w.png]

Thanks for help, sorry if format is bad, this is my first post.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a couple of subqueries to meet your requirement. Let us break it down.

First, you need the total value of orders from each customer. You're very close to the correct query for that.  It should be

```
               SELECT orders.customerNumber,
                      SUM(orderdetails.quantityOrdered * orderdetails.priceEach) owed
                 FROM orders
                 JOIN orderdetails ON  orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber
             GROUP BY orders.customerNumber
```

This subquery's result set gives customerNumber and owed, the amount owed. Notice that orders::orderdetails  is a one::many relationship, so we're sure we're counting each detail just once, so the SUMs will be correct.

Next we need the amount paid by each customer. This subquery is fairly simple.

```
               SELECT customerNumber,
                      SUM(amount) paid
                 FROM payments
                GROUP BY customerNumber
```

Now for the operation you're missing in your question: we need to join these two subqueries to your customers table.

```
SELECT customers.customerName, customers.customerNumber
       owed.owed - paid.paid balance
  FROM customers
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT orders.customerNumber,
                      SUM(orderdetails.quantityOrdered * orderdetails.priceEach) owed
                 FROM orders
                 JOIN orderdetails ON  orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber
             GROUP BY orders.customerNumber
       ) paid ON customers.customerNumber = paid.customerNumber
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT customerNumber,
                      SUM(amount) paid
                 FROM payments
                GROUP BY customerNumber
       ) owed ON customers.customerNumber = owed.customerNumber
```

See how this works? We join a table and two subqueries. Each subquery has either zero or one rows for each row in the table, so we need not use SUMs or GROUP BY in the outer query.

There's only one complication left: what if a customer has never paid anything? Then the value of paid.paid will be NULL after the LEFT JOIN operation. That will force the value of `owed - paid` to be NULL.  So we need more smarts in the SELECT statement to yield correct sums.

```
SELECT customers.customerName, customers.customerNumber
       COALESCE(owed.owed,0) - COALESCE(paid.paid,0) balance
       ...
```

[COALESCE(a,b)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is equivalent to *if a is not null then a else b*.

**Pro tip** In queries or subqueries with JOIN operations, always mention `table.column` instead of just `column`. The next person to work on your query will thank you.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much and great job at explaining it <3